# Getting warning while deleting custom fields

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type and added custom fields in the WordPress backend as you can see in the screenshot [image]

But now when I try to delete this custom field, getting this warning

`You do not have permission to do that.`

I am bit confused as why this warning is showing up as I am already logged in with Administrator account.

I have developed a plugin for creating custom post type below is the code

```
public function charities_register_plugin() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Charities', 'charities'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Charity', 'charities'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'charities'),
        'add_new_item' => _x('Add New Charity', 'charities'),
        'edit_item' => _x('Edit Charity', 'charities'),
        'new_item' => _x('New Charity', 'charities'),
        'view_item' => _x('View Charity', 'charities'),
        'search_items' => _x('Search Charity', 'charities'),
        'not_found' => _x('No charities found', 'charities'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x('No charities found in Trash', 'charities'),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x('Parent Charity:', 'charities'),
        'menu_name' => _x('Charities', 'charities'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,

        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Allow Admin to create charities',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'revisions','custom-fields'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array("slug" => "mycharities",'with_front'=>FALSE)
    );

    register_post_type('charities', $args);

}
```

And trigger it using

`add_action('init', array($this, 'charities_register_plugin'));`

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me custom post type code you have created in functions.php

Comment: @Arshad, I have added my custom post type code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your args and let me know if your problem resolved:

```
     $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'capability_type' => 'charities',
    'capabilities' => array(
                     'publish_posts' => 'publish_charities',
                     'edit_posts' => 'edit_charities',
                     'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_charities',
                     'delete_posts' => 'delete_charities',
                     'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_charities',
                     'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_charities',
                     'edit_post' => 'edit_charities',
                     'delete_post' => 'delete_charities',
                     'read_post' => 'read_charities',
                    ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'Allow Admin to create charities',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'revisions','custom-fields'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "mycharities",'with_front'=>FALSE)
);
```

Comment: if I tried to use the above mentioned code then I can't even access the edit charity page (custom_post).